# How to access hadoop Web UI from docker toolbox

Tags: docker

After I put my file in hdfs then I tried localhost:50070 on my browser but it said cannot reach the site. Do I need to configure my xml file in order to access the web ui?

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose that port.

```
docker run \
-d \
-p 50070:50070 \
--name hadoop \
hadoop
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering me. I am totally new in docker and hadoop. So is that means i need to expose the port before i run inside the container. I am using sequenceiq/hadoop-docker image. So before that when i want to get in to the container i use $ docker run -v /c/users/test:/test -it sequenceid/hadoop-docker:2.7.0 /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash. so is that mean now i need to add $docker run -v /c/users/test:/test -dp 50070:50070 -it sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.0 /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! BTW `-d` means run as daemon, so if you use `-it`, there is no necessary to use `-d`

Comment: Hi, it still show the site can't be reach when i browse localhost:50070 in my host os windows. This showed in my container ports 2122/tcp, 8030-8033/tcp, 8040/tcp, 8042/tcp, 8088/tcp, 19888/tcp, 49707/tcp, 50010/tcp, 50020/tcp, 50075/tcp, 50090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50070->50070/tcp

Comment: Can you make sure that the HDFS service is running by curl/httpie http://localhost:50070/ ?

Comment: Hi i able to access alrdy because I m using docker toolbox so need to use the docker machine IP address instead of just localhost but thankss for solving my problem previously.